# How to use .net delegate in vba

Tags: .net, vba, delegates

I have a .net DLL written in C# which exposes some delegates. Now, they are visible in VBA Object Explorer and appear as a 'Class'. But how can I instantiate it and make it point to a VBA function with the same signature and the pass it back to a C# function which takes that delegate as an argument?

I should be able to do that, right!? My DLL is registered for COM interop, is there any COM attributes that must decorate the delegates or what?

Thanks, Andrei!

Answer (score 1):

Use late binding, you won't be able to use the VBA IntelliSense to program, call the functions with the right parameter:

For example:
Instantiate you class

```
Private obj As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("NAMESPACE.CLASS")
```

and use the methods from your class

```
obj.METHOD(a,b,c)
```

If you need to register you DDL programmaticaly, you can use

```
Shell "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe c:\MYDLL.dll /codebase"
```